# Copying as a reference or Clone?

Tags: c#, .net

Even though I am doing C# code since long, today I got confused in one basic fundamental. To answer see below code.

Note: RR is a View-Object from my xaml file, and Findname method is used in ViewModel to find any child UI components using name.

```
public FuncA(CustomRibbonWindow RR)
{
    DockManager XX=RR.FindName("DockManager_Bottom") as DockManager;
}
```

Is object inside XX copied as reference or just like value?

I also checked return type of FindName() function which was **object** so had further question like : Is there any difference between **object** and **Object**? ( I mean **object** here telling to copy as value only while **Object** return type may referring copy as reference) .

Forgive me if questions are too silly that may irritate you, but its very important for me to know.

Comment: My 1st question is not duplicated. Please...!

Comment: `XX` is referring to your `DockManager_Bottom` control, it is not cloned.

Comment: It will not be cloned. It is just the same reference. You can test it by comparing the objects using `Object.ReferenceEquals` method. Also tag user, so that he'll get notifications. Like this @Pratik

Comment: Thanks Sriram and hantoun.